# Bootstrap3 toggle switch with ajax update to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello and thank you for looking.

I have the slick new toggle effect for the checkbox (boostrap3) in place.
I would like to update my database each time the toggle is clicked.
A simple On or OFF entry will be perfect.  Ofcourse it needs to be without
a page refresh.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="setQuickVar1">Enable Notifications<input id="QuickVar1" type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-size="small" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="ON" data-off-color="default" data-off-text="OFF" ></span>
                                  <div id="resultQuickVar1"></div>
```

**Javascript/Ajax:**

```
var handleQuickSidebarToggler2 = function () {
        // quick sidebar toggler
        $('#setQuickVar1').click(function (e) {
            $('body').toggleClass('make-switch');
            $.post("quickRightSidebarDBUpdate.php", {"quickVar1a": $('#QuickVar1').val()}, 
            function(data) {
                $('#resultQuickVar1').html(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

(I added a div to show my results)

**quickRightSidebarDBUpdate.php**

```
if ($_POST['quickVar1a']):
    $quickVar1a = $_POST['quickVar1a'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE test SET field1 = " . $quickVar1a . ""; 
endif;
```

I think I am close since the Db does get an entry of "on".  I can set the check box to "checked" or leave it as above in the code and each time it enters "on" to the BD.

I'm not sure how the entry of "on" is even generated.

Thank you greatly for any help.

### **ANSWER BELOW...Well it works..but it's not pretty**

I did an ugly version of what I want and it's working.    Here's what I did.

**HTML**

```
 <span id="setQuickVar1">Enable Notifications<input id="QuickVar1" type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-size="small" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="ON" data-off-color="default" data-off-text="OFF" <?php echo $checked;?>  ></span>
                                  <div id="resultQuickVar1"></div>
```

**Javascript/Ajax**

```
    // Handles quick sidebar toggler2
    var handleQuickSidebarToggler2 = function () {
        // quick sidebar toggler
        $('#setQuickVar1').click(function (e) {
            $('body').toggleClass('make-switch');
            //$(this).toggleClass('make-switch');
            $.post("quickRightSidebarDBUpdate.php", {"quickVar1a": $('#QuickVar1').val()}, 
            function(data) {
                $('#resultQuickVar1').html(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

**quickRightSidebarDBUpdate.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test`";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo 'Finding:'.$r['quickVar1'].'<br>';
if($r['quickVar1'] == 'ON')
$quickVar1a = 'OFF';
else
$quickVar1a = 'ON';
$sql = "UPDATE test SET quickVar1 ='" . $quickVar1a . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
echo 'Updating To: '.$quickVar1a.'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

**JS**

```
$('#setQuickVar1').on('click', function() {
    var checkStatus = this.checked ? 'ON' : 'OFF';

    $.post("quickRightSidebarDBUpdate.php", {"quickVar1a": checkStatus}, 
    function(data) {
        $('#resultQuickVar1').html(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['quickVar1a'])):
    $quickVar1a = $_POST['quickVar1a'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE test SET field1 = '" . $quickVar1a . "'"; 
endif;
```

*code not tested, let me know if does NOT work :)*

### Update 2

Here is a proper SQL query for the toggle:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE test SET field1 = '".$quickVar1a."' where field1 != '".$quickVar1a."'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!  I tried your code and it did not work.

Comment: Where is the part that is not working? JS or PHP? I think you meant in the PHP side. I just showed you how to get the ON and OFF value if checked or not. In your php, you need to deal with the toggle logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

HTML:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"  id="h_activate" name="host" value="1">
<p id="just"></p>
```

**Ajax:**

```
$('#h_activate').on('change', function(event, state) {

   var checkStatus = this.checked ? 'ON' : 'OFF';

$.ajax({
            url:"check.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{"toogle": checkStatus},
            success:function(data){
                
                $('#just').html(data);
                
            }
        });

});
```

**PHP: check.php**

```
 var_dump($_POST); //Allow you to see if php page getting post value or not.

 $toogle= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['toogle']);

    if(isset($toogle) && $toogle!=='')
    {
        $sql="update status set toogle='$toogle'";
        if($conn->query($sql))
        {
         echo 'updated success';
        }

    }else{
         echo 'error: not updated';
    }
```

instead of directly updating the database first check ajax giving any response or not.